# Add on premise cluster to vscode-kubernetes-tools

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, snapcraft

I would like to configure the VSCode extension (vscode-kubernetes-tools) to be able to manage a cluster using `~/.kube/config`  but I get no feedback from the ui nor `/var/log/syslog`. The cluster is deployed locally (no azure, nor minikube)

Info:
os : ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
vscode installed using snap
kubectl installed using snap

Didn't find any issues on https://github.com/Azure/vscode-kubernetes-tools/issues